# How can I force chrome to get the geolocation from GPS module connected to a USB port instead of getting it from router IP?

Tags: google-chrome, gps

I'm working on a certain project that uses RasberryPi debian 7 google chrome to open get some work done, the thing is, the server (I made it with django) asks the rasberry pi about its location.

RasberryPi's google chrome gets the location from the wifi IP location service.
How can I change it to get the location from a GPS module I connected to RasberryPi USB port?

I configured the GPS module and it's ready the location well and everythin works fine, now I only need to force chrome to get its location from that GPS module.

Comment: I don't see any relation to programming here.

Comment: @KlausD.  Programming maybe chrome plugin or some sort of software to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have RasberryPi but this way works in Android:  Start a native GPS app alongside Chrome, and Chrome will use the GPS positions that have already been produced for the native app.